# DefaultRolloverStrategy Log4j2 not working (programmatically)

Tags: log4j2

I need to create a rollingfile appender and set the amount of logfiles during runtime with log4j2. So I use the following code to achive that:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

DefaultRolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.newBuilder()
        .withMax("4")
        .withMin("1")
        .withFileIndex("max")
        .withConfig(config)
        .withCompressionLevelStr(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION + "")
        .build();

PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config)
        .withPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%5p] %pid --- %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wEx")
        .build();

RollingFileAppender appender = RollingFileAppender.newBuilder().setConfiguration(config)
        .withName("TraceFileAppender")
        .withLayout(layout)
        .withFileName("log.log")
        .withFilePattern("log.%d{yyyy-MM-ddHHmmSSS}.log")
        .withPolicy(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("20KB")
        .withStrategy(strategy)
        .build();

appender.start();
config.addAppender(appender);

LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getRootLogger();
loggerConfig.setLevel(Level.toLevel("DEBUG"));
loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
```

This is working fine except from the max amount of files... I`m getting more files than the 4 in my strategy.... what is wrong? Any help is welcome!

Thanks in advance,

Regards Peter

Answer (score 2):

pfff took me a while but I got it working... Not a lot information about programmaticaly changing log4j2 appenders here so this is my solution:

```
LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext) LogManager.getContext(false);
        Configuration config = ctx.getConfiguration();

        PathCondition[] pathConditions = new PathCondition[1];
        pathConditions[0] = IfAccumulatedFileCount.createFileCountCondition(Integer.parseInt(expire));

        DeleteAction action = DeleteAction.createDeleteAction("C:\\logs\\BuddyServer\\", true, 1, false, null, pathConditions, null, config);
        Action[] actions = new Action[1];
        actions[0] = action;

        DefaultRolloverStrategy strategy = DefaultRolloverStrategy.newBuilder()
                .withMax(expire)
                .withCustomActions(actions)
                .withMin("1")
                .withFileIndex("max")
                .withConfig(config)
                .withCompressionLevelStr(Deflater.NO_COMPRESSION + "")  
                .build();


        PatternLayout layout = PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config)
                .withPattern("%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%5p] %pid --- %-40.40logger{39} : %m%n%wEx")
                .build();

        RollingFileAppender appender = RollingFileAppender.newBuilder().setConfiguration(config)
                .withName("TraceFileAppender")
                .withLayout(layout)
                .withFileName(file + ".log")
                .withFilePattern(file + ".%d{yyyy-MM-ddHHmmSSS}.log")
                .withPolicy(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy(segment))
                .withStrategy(strategy)
                .build();

        appender.start();
        config.addAppender(appender);

        LoggerConfig loggerConfig = config.getRootLogger();
        loggerConfig.setLevel(Level.toLevel(buddyConfig.getOption("log", "verbose").toUpperCase()));
        loggerConfig.addAppender(appender, null, null);
```

Comment: The solution is incomplete but gives some idea. Thanks :)